# How do I implement a Generic Comparator?

Tags: java, generics

So I'm trying to use insertion sort with a generic comparator that must be passed in.  I can't change the method name.  How would I go about implementing a comparator to pass into the insertionSort method?  I'm new to java and object oriented programming.

The test is just a junit test.

```
public class SortUtil {


public static <T> void insertionSort(ArrayList<T> dataSet, int left, int right, Comparator<? super T> Comparator)
{

    for(int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
    {
        T item = dataSet.get(i);

        int j;
        if (dataSet != null)
        {
        for(j = i - 1; (j >= left) && (Comparator.compare(dataSet.get(j), item)) > 0; j--)
        {
            dataSet.set(j + 1, dataSet.get(j)) ;
        }
        dataSet.set(j + 1, item);
        }
    }

}


public void test() {        
    Comparator<? super T> Comp = null;

    ArrayList<T> temp = (ArrayList<T>) SortUtil.generateBestCase(10);

    SortUtil.insertionSort(temp, 0, temp.size(), Comp);






}

}
```

Comment: How do the objects you pass in compare with one another?  Would it make any sense to try and perform an `.equals` call on them?

Comment: It has to be able to compare any type passed in, whether its strings or integers, in order to sort them.

Comment: I also must use the Comparator.compare to sort.

Comment: So at the bare minimum, they implement `Comparable`.  I don't know if you want to compare `Integer` with `String`, but what is `T` defined as?

Comment: I don't think it needs to compare integers to strings, but just different ArrayList types, so a list of strings, or a list of integers.  The T is the generic type.  Should the T be set as my class name?  The class name is SortUtil.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the full class definition so I can see what `T` actually is.

Comment: as of now it's just public class SortUtil

Comment: ...Edit your question with this information.

Comment: Then within that is insertionSort, just not sure how to go about making a Comparator<? super T> Comp to pass into the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insertionSort()` is generic. It uses `T`. `test()` is not. It should uses whatever specific type you want to test with. In `test()`, you don't make a `Comparator<? super T>`, you make a `Comparator<Integer>` or `Comparator<String>` or any other random specific `Comparator` you like, the only requirement is that the type has to be the same as or a parent of the type you use for the `ArrayList temp` (which should likewise be an `ArrayList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<String>`, or etc.).

To create a custom `Comparator<Integer>`, do this:

```
Comparator<Integer> comp = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        // Your code here. Check the documentation for how this should behave.
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that make more sense now.  I'm still getting an error when trying to use the comparator.  Do I have to make a custom override comparator in my insertionSort method too?

Comment: @cjoy `insertionSort` should be fine as is. How are you creating the `Comparator` in `test()`?

Comment: I'm using Comparator<Integer> Comp = null; It's been giving me a nullpoint exception once it runs Comparator.compare

Comment: @cjoy That's roughly equivalent to giving `insertionSort` an empty void and saying it's a `Comparator`. See my edit for how to actually make one.

Comment: Awesome, yeah that's just what the test needed.  Thanks!!